# How to run validate cluster test without taking cluster offline?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012, failovercluster

I'm trying to run "Validate a Cluster" wizard but when I selected `Run all test` it gave a warning that running storage test will result in role failure. What test can I run in `Run only tests I select` that will not bring any anything offline or cause interruptions in services?

Comment: This is one of those questions where the answer is "You can't have your cake and eat it too". You want to troubleshoot a cluster without taking the cluster offline as part of the test, but then what good would the test be if it isn't a full test?

Answer (score 1):

The tests involve forcing a failover to ensure everything works. I wouldn't run the validation unless you can handle it failing over as part of the test.

Comment: I do not administer the cluster, therefore can not make that desicion to failover. Recently we had several failures and I am just trying to understand what caused it and help troubleshoot it.